# Timer publisher with initial fire now

Tags: ios, combine

I have a simple timer publisher that fires every 10 seconds.

```
Timer
    .publish(every: 10, on: .main, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
    .map { _ in ... }
    .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] in
        ...
    })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

However, the first time it fires is in 10 seconds from now. Can I set it to fire its first value *now*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively to creating another publisher, you can simply `prepend` to your timer publisher:

```swift
Timer
    .publish(every: 10, on: .main, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
    .prepend(Date())
    .map { _ in ... }
    .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] in
        ...
    })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

The above code has the same effect of publishing a value right away, and let the timer publish the other values.

Comment: Yep, this is what I ended up doing!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve what I wanted, but I had to add another publisher:

```
let timer = Timer
                .publish(every: 10, on: .main, in: .common)
                .autoconnect()
let initial = Just(Date.init())

timer.merge(with: initial)
         .map { _ in ... }
         .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] in
              ...
         })
         .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Comment: I can't think of a better way. :) You might use a different verb (`append` maybe) but the use of a Just to "fire" right now seems the correct option.